# How can I have 2 triggers in an Azure Function - .NET 8

Tags: azure-functions

Having 2 Run methods does not work. The following code:

```
public class Functions
{
    private readonly ILogger<Functions> _logger;

    public Functions(ILogger<Functions> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [Function("RunNow")]
    public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] HttpRequest req)
    {

        string? message = req.Query["message"];

        if (_logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Trace))
            _logger.LogTrace($"RunNow?message={message} called");

        return new OkObjectResult("RunNow successfully completed.");
    }

    [Function("MidnightRun")]
    public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 9 * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
    {
        if (_logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug))
            _logger.LogDebug($"MidnightRun executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

        try
        {
            // Worker.ProcessAllPendingItems(null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, $"MidnightRun threw error {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Throws the following exceptions:

```
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.759Z] Worker failed to load function: 'RunNow' with functionId: '3842070629'.
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.759Z] Worker failed to load function: 'MidnightRun' with functionId: '2487480743'.
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.760Z] Result: Failure
Exception: System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found for 'LouisHowe.function.Functions Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Run(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest)'.
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.760Z] Result: Failure
Exception: System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found for 'LouisHowe.function.Functions Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Run(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest)'.
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.761Z]    at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImplCommon(String name, Int32 genericParameterCount, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.761Z]    at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImplCommon(String name, Int32 genericParameterCount, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.762Z]    at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.762Z]    at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.763Z]    at System.Type.GetMethod(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.763Z]    at System.Type.GetMethod(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.764Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultMethodInfoLocator.GetMethod(String pathToAssembly, String entryPoint) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultMethodInfoLocator.cs:line 32
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.764Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultMethodInfoLocator.GetMethod(String pathToAssembly, String entryPoint) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultMethodInfoLocator.cs:line 32
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.765Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Definition.GrpcFunctionDefinition..ctor(FunctionLoadRequest loadRequest, IMethodInfoLocator methodInfoLocator) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\Definition\GrpcFunctionDefinition.cs:line 56
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.765Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Definition.GrpcFunctionDefinition..ctor(FunctionLoadRequest loadRequest, IMethodInfoLocator methodInfoLocator) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\Definition\GrpcFunctionDefinition.cs:line 56
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.766Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Rpc.RpcExtensions.ToFunctionDefinition(FunctionLoadRequest loadRequest, IMethodInfoLocator methodInfoLocator) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\RpcExtensions.cs:line 118
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.766Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Rpc.RpcExtensions.ToFunctionDefinition(FunctionLoadRequest loadRequest, IMethodInfoLocator methodInfoLocator) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\RpcExtensions.cs:line 118
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.767Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.GrpcWorker.FunctionLoadRequestHandler(FunctionLoadRequest request, IFunctionsApplication application, IMethodInfoLocator methodInfoLocator) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\GrpcWorker.cs:line 268
Stack:    at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImplCommon(String name, Int32 genericParameterCount, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.767Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.GrpcWorker.FunctionLoadRequestHandler(FunctionLoadRequest request, IFunctionsApplication application, IMethodInfoLocator methodInfoLocator) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\GrpcWorker.cs:line 268
Stack:    at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImplCommon(String name, Int32 genericParameterCount, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.768Z]    at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.769Z]    at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.770Z]    at System.Type.GetMethod(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.770Z]    at System.Type.GetMethod(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.771Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultMethodInfoLocator.GetMethod(String pathToAssembly, String entryPoint) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultMethodInfoLocator.cs:line 32
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.771Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Invocation.DefaultMethodInfoLocator.GetMethod(String pathToAssembly, String entryPoint) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Invocation\DefaultMethodInfoLocator.cs:line 32
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.772Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Definition.GrpcFunctionDefinition..ctor(FunctionLoadRequest loadRequest, IMethodInfoLocator methodInfoLocator) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\Definition\GrpcFunctionDefinition.cs:line 56
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.772Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Definition.GrpcFunctionDefinition..ctor(FunctionLoadRequest loadRequest, IMethodInfoLocator methodInfoLocator) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\Definition\GrpcFunctionDefinition.cs:line 56
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.773Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Rpc.RpcExtensions.ToFunctionDefinition(FunctionLoadRequest loadRequest, IMethodInfoLocator methodInfoLocator) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\RpcExtensions.cs:line 118
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.773Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Rpc.RpcExtensions.ToFunctionDefinition(FunctionLoadRequest loadRequest, IMethodInfoLocator methodInfoLocator) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\RpcExtensions.cs:line 118
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.774Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.GrpcWorker.FunctionLoadRequestHandler(FunctionLoadRequest request, IFunctionsApplication application, IMethodInfoLocator methodInfoLocator) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\GrpcWorker.cs:line 268.
[2024-01-29T21:57:29.774Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.GrpcWorker.FunctionLoadRequestHandler(FunctionLoadRequest request, IFunctionsApplication application, IMethodInfoLocator methodInfoLocator) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\GrpcWorker.cs:line 268.
```

So 2 `Run` methods are not allowed. So what can I do to have both a timer and http get trigger?

Comment: ... name the methods differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I have 2 triggers in an Azure Function - .NET 8

You can below **`code`** to get desired results:

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp119
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik Bojja, HTTP Trigger function is called ");
            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
            return response;
        }
    }
    public class Function2
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function2(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }
        [Function("Function2")]
    public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Hello Rithwik Bojja, C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

        if (myTimer.ScheduleStatus is not null)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");
        }
    }
}
}
```

**`csproj:`**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**`local.settings.json:`**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. One follow up question. Is it better to have two classes as you showed or to have one class with two methods as @IanKemp suggested? Or does it not matter? (One class makes life a little easier for me.) TIA

Comment: AFAIK, it is better to have two @DavidThielen